# Scipy spsolve is order of magnitude slower than matlab mldivide

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

Ok, so I have a linear system. A is sparse 29791 by 29791 with 202771 stored elements. B is 29791 by 1 with 4561 stored elements.

I have tried solving this system by storing A as csr_matrix and as csc_matrix, and B as a regular numpy array. Both csr and csc matrices take about a minute to solve. Then, I tried saving the triplets (row, column, data) in csv format, and importing this in matlab and then doing:

```
Asp = sparse(data(:, 1), data(:, 2), data(:, 3))
P = Asp\b
```

This takes around a second, if not less. Why is matlab nearly 2 orders of magnitude faster than scipy, and how can I speed this computation up? Even matlab mldivide takes less than 2 seconds.

```
A = csc_matrix((data, (np.asarray(rows), np.asarray(cols))), shape=A_shape)
P = spsolve(A, csc_matrix(B))
```

I expect the scipy spsolve to be at max twice as slow as matlab backslash, but its not.

Comment: Convince a for profit company to rework `sparse` module!  Years ago when I did FEM work in MATLAB, building the stiffness matrix took as long as that solve.  Have you played with the permutation parameter?  How about the sparse iterative solvers?

Comment: `spsolve` can also try to use `Scikits.umfpack`; I don't know what advantages that has.

Comment: Maybe this package https://github.com/haasad/PyPardisoProject (MKL Pardiso wrapper) helps?

Comment: Using `spsolve` from `scikits.umfpack` makes all the difference, I guess what we are seeing is Python overhead.